# Generative AI detector for text (tells whether a text was written by a human or not)

Tags: text-processing, artificial-intelligence, deep-fake

I want to quickly **tell whether a text was written by a human or by an AI** (such as ChatGPT, GPT, LaMDA, BART, etc).

Ideally something that can be used online without installing anything, just with a textbox to paste the text I want to check.

Bonus if the detector:

- is free to use.
- does not need registration.
- supports several generators, such as GPT and LaMDA.

Comment: Related on MSE: [How can we identify ChatGPT-generated posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384457/241919).

Answer (score 3):

[GPT-2 Output Detector Demo](https://openai-openai-detector.hf.space/) on HuggingFace allows users to either enter the text into the textbox directly or use it as an API. It is free to use and does not need registration.

> This is an online demo of the GPT-2 output detector model, based on the [`/Transformers`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/commit/1c542df7e554a2014051dd09becf60f157fed524) implementation of [RoBERTa](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11692). Enter some text in the text box; the predicted probabilities will be displayed below. The results start to get reliable after around 50 tokens.

When entering the text directly into the textbox, it will show a graph on how fake (AI-generated) or real (human-generated) it is.

When using it as an API by adding a GET argument, like `https://openai-openai-detector.hf.space/?This%20is%20a%20test`, it will return a JSON message:

```
{"all_tokens": 4, "used_tokens": 4, "real_probability": 0.016693303361535072, "fake_probability": 0.9833067059516907}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply go to [this](https://platform.openai.com/ai-text-classifier) website and paste your text. It is created by OpenAI(creators of ChatGPT). Just paste the text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. After processing it will show you results.

Website - https://platform.openai.com/ai-text-classifier

Comment: Note that this needs registration.

Comment: Not free to use, you pay by handing over your phone number.